# Executing existing stored procedure to fill a new table in SQL server 2008 R2 without using openrowset

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How to fill a table using a stored procedure without using open row set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT YourTables (Col1, Col2)
EXECUTE YourStoredProcedure 'SomeParameter'
```

Comment: I did the same, Insert tablename(cols)
Execute ProcName  '(FiscalYear,par2)'
Now it is giving me the error
Error converting data type varchar to int.
but Fiscal year is of "INT" type. Help.

Comment: If that is the exact statement you are executing, sounds like you proc takes an INTEGER parameter, and you are supplying it with a VARCHAR that is not a valid integer. e.g. EXECUTE ProcName 'NotAnInteger' would error, EXECUTE ProcName 2012 should be OK. So check you are calling the proc correctly. If this doesn't help, please edit your question and add all information about exactly what you are executing

Comment: You can just pass the values, making sure you pass them in the same order as defined in the sproc if there are multiple. Or, you can name them:
EXECUTE YourStoredProcedure @FiscalYear=2012

Comment: Hey @AdaTheDev it worked for me thanks a ton. 
Now the problem is i want parameters to be passed by user instead of passing the name of the parameters myself.
 I have 7 tables and i need to pass the value of any of the table which is recently updated/inserted/deleted to the newly created table automatically. i.e if i update "table 1" it should be reflected in "new table" with timestamp.